# Receiving and Manipulating RTSP stream using FFMPEG library in Java Application

Tags: java, ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp, live-streaming

Hope you all be fine and doing great.

I am currently working on a Java Web Application. I am getting Streaming video using RTSP URL. This URL is like:

```
 rtsp://---.---.---./6ca714ae28e52f31
```

I have been able to capture video, diplay/listen it and store it in .mp4 file using FFMPEG with the following command:

```
fmpeg -i rtsp://username:password@---.---.---.---/6ca714ae28e52f31 -f mov e:/bay.mov (with authentication)
```

Now, I want to achieve the same in my Java application using ffmped library. I am sure if all this possible through commands then It will also be possible using its library. But unfortunately couldn't get any working useful material regarding this on web.

So, I simply want to ask that:

```
1.  How can I fetch Streams using this RTSP URL in my Java Application with FFMPEG library
2.  How can I Manipulate this fetched streaming such as start, stop, end etc.
3.  How can I store this streaming in media file in playable form in any specified format.
```

I have found a FFMPEG's Java Rapper JJMPEG. Now I have two options either to issue FFMPEG command to CMD using Java Application or use JJMPEG library directly. Don't know which one will be better choice.

Thanks for your time and considerations.

Comment: I didn't get any proper tutorial for FFMPEG's Java Wrapper. So, I am using FFMPEG commands now from inside Java Application. Please tell me if you found anything useful or you need help.